# Http response file download not working in Internet explorer and chrome (C#, Asp.net)

Tags: c#, asp.net, internet-explorer, google-chrome

I write a file download method to download file from server to client machine in C# asp.net

I wrote the following code:

```
Response.ContentType = ReturnExtension(System.IO.Path.GetExtension(file.Name));

                    Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + file.Name);

                    Response.TransmitFile(strRequest);

                    Response.End();
```

This will work fine in Firefox and Chrome, but not in IE.

Comment: When you say it doesn't download does it open in the browser window? Do nothing? And can you confirm that your ReturnExtension method returns a mime type? The name doesn't sound like it does but thought I should check... Also does your filename have spaces? or anything else like that that could be confusing that header?

Comment: The spaces in the file name should not make a problem, but you have to have a proper ContentType, which file extensions are not.

Comment: my ReturnExtension method check the extension of the file and return mime type according to the extention, if the extenstion of file is .bmp it will return string "image/bmp". when i click download button no save or open dialogue appears, but in firefox and chrome all thing working fine,but in internet explorer nothing happen, im not getting the cause of this issue kindly someone give me any hint , thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing similar issue in some versions of IE and had to set Cache-Control header to make the download working properly:

```
response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.Private);
```

Answer (score 0):

try to put a `Response.Clear()` on top of your code.