# Can download a file from WCF service using firefox and chrome but not Edge and Internet Explorer 11

Tags: c#, wcf

I' m trying to download a file from my WCF service. All is working great. But one problem is that Internet Explorer 11 and Edge browser, can't download the file while chrome and firefox can. Here's the code I used :

```
string result = GetDocument();
WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingResponse.StatusCode = System.Net.HttpStatusCode.Created;
WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingResponse.ContentType = "application/octect-stream";
WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingResponse.Headers.Add("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + result);
return File.OpenRead(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

As found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6993090/http-response-file-download-not-working-in-internet-explorer-and-chrome-c-asp),

Someone was facing similar issue in some versions of IE and had to set Cache-Control header to make the download working properly:

```
response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.Private);
```

Comment: I 'm using WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingResponse, so there's no way to adjust the cache. I'm not sure if there's a way to do this in web.config