# Excel file download using MS Edge

Tags: javascript, excel, download, microsoft-edge

My app creates an excel file, server side, from a database extraction.

A post request sends parameters to the server that the server then uses to query the database.

The server uses these parameters to extract data convert the data to an excel file (xlsx), then saves the file with a certain file-name as per the parameters sent to the server.

The server responds to the post request by sending the file-name to the browser.

The browser then creates a link using the filename and other predefined parameters to download the file by the following instructions:

```
var link = 'http://host-name/path-to-file/excel-file.xlxs'; // the link that is created by the js in the browser
window.location = link; // the file is downloaded
```

This works in chrome, firefox, opera and safari, in these browsers, the file downloads no problem.

However; when running in Microsoft-edge, the file is not downloaded and this appears in the page.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue here is that this method of downloading files is not actually downloading the file. I was using `javascript` to instruct the `browser` to open the `excel` file, `window.location = link;`. Which tells the `browser`, go to a that link, and open whatever you find at that address. Which is normally an `HTML` file or something else `transpiled` into `HTML`. This can in some cases be also be a `.pdf` or the sort of file that modern `web-browsers` are able to interpret and run.

Now, the reason this was mostly working is; browsers like `chrome` and `firefox` are smart enough to know that they cannot interpret and display `excel` files, so instead, they download them. Pretty smart right. However; `microsoft-edge` is not so clever as its more proven compatriots. It tries to interpret and run the file, which of course it cannot. What this then leads to; is a grand display of nonsense; as you can see from screen-grab in my question above.

My problem here was actually a deeper rooted issue of technology mismatch. I had since migrated to using a more modern stack, replacing my plain `node.js` server with `express`. Moving the `front-end` out of a `cross-origin` `tomcat` java-container application-server model (which was causing most of my headaches on a daily bases since I was coding `javascript`) to a `same-origin` environment using `webpack` along with `express`.

And as you might know, using `webpack` brings a whole new dimension to the `front-end` that was not available before when we were using the 'old approach' to `web-dev`.

Most of the improvements in using `webpack` came from its ability to bring 'node.js' to the front end.

It has made my life as a dev 150% easier and the type of problem as described in my question above is now a thing of the past. `javascript` for the win! The moral for me here is that sometimes that aren't any quick fixes, and you just have to do things properly.

Answer (score 1):

Someone was facing similar issue in some versions of IE and had to set Cache-Control header to make the download working properly:

```
response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.Private);
```

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6993090/http-response-file-download-not-working-in-internet-explorer-and-chrome-c-asp)

Comment: I am using JavaScript with an Ajax request.